# What is the Html5 API which retrieves image metadata such as file size, format (jpeg, png ..) from image file?

Tags: image, html, canvas, metadata

I want to retrieve metadata (width, hight, format ..) from image file (jpeg, png, bmp etc.) in the Html5.
I can use Canvas Api to deal width image.
However, I cannot find Api to retrieve metadata from a file.
Does anyone can know me?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [this little lib](http://blog.nihilogic.dk/2008/08/imageinfo-reading-image-metadata-with.html) might do the trick for you.